# ASP.NET web api rewriting to async for DocumentDB

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb

I'm looking at replacing good ol' entity framework 6 and MSSQL by Azure Cosmos DB and the DocumentDB C# api. The DocumentDB library has only async methods while our controllers aren't async. Of course, rewriting the controllers to async is no big deal and has no impact. But from the controllers, many different helper classes are called that also have database actions in them.

I've read that I should **never** use the Wait() method because it can lock the different threads. Does that mean I would have to re-write the entire call stack to async, just to use the DocumentDB library? That would be a massive undertaking in my solution and adding async has no actual benefit for us.

Comment: Is it possible to run the helper methods on a different thread? Then maybe you can use Task.Run() to run your helper methods and use await on that call?

Comment: No, you need to change everything to async because you *already* waste CPU by blocking while waiting for the database. ADO.NET *already* has asynchronous methods, eg `ExecuteReaderAsync`, why call the *blocking* ones? The only benefit is to the cloud provider - you end up using larger and more VMs to handle the same load

Comment: @m4ttsson pushing a blocking call to another thread still wastes one thread

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, we use the old-school blocking methods because we need sequential processing anyway. It's a synchronization service. So an external system offers an object, the web-api processes it (in this example, publishes data to Magento2), and then returns the result to the original caller so it knows whether the synchronization was successful.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes. But it would also be possible to rewrite the code base step by step to remove those Task.Run calls. Instead of rewriting it in one big push. Incremental rewrites would also be easier to get past management or someone higher up.

Comment: @Erik change your methods first, and measure how many *more* requests can be served by the same VM. Calculate how many VMs you can turn off after that. *Any* IO in Windows is asynchronous. `Sync` is emulated by blocking while waiting for a response. By using blocking calls now you are simply wasting CPU. That blocking doesn't mean the CPU is idle either - waking a sleeping thread is expensive so a block starts by spinwaiting, then puts the thread to sleep.

Comment: @Erik that's an invalid reason. Asynchronous doesn't mean non-sequential. You are confusing it with concurrency. You don't have any synchronous operations right now anyway, unless you server only *one* requests at a time. Web requests *are* conccurrent by nature. You have no reason to use blocking calls. BTW `await` *guarantees* sequential processing, just like a blocking call. The code after the async call won't run unless the async call finishes and returns

Comment: @m4ttsson the same can be said about going top-down and changing *some* database calls each time. Management will be happier to know they can shut down VMs and pay *less*

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, thanks for the insight. I've always just assumed async was only interesting for UI developers and didn't add anything useful to web-api's. I guess I'll be spending my next weekends in visual studio... ;)